# Ambiguous name detected

Tags: excel, vba

My code is not working properly with an error message stating ambiguous name detected: WOS
Here's my code below. How do I get this code to work?

```
Sub WOS()

Function WOS(BOP, StartPosn As Range)
Set myRange = Range(StartPosn, StartPosn.End(xlToRight))
Dim lupvals()
ReDim lupvals(1 To myRange.Cells.Count)
i = 1
For Each cll In myRange.Cells
lupvals(i) = Application.Sum(Range(StartPosn, cll))
i = i + 1
Next cll
xx = Application.Match(BOP, lupvals)
If IsError(xx) And lupvals(1) >= BOP Then
WOS = BOP / lupvals(1)
Else
If xx = UBound(lupvals) And (BOP - lupvals(xx)) > 0 Then
WOS = "n/a"
Else
WOS = xx + (BOP - lupvals(xx)) / myRange(xx + 1)
End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: unless there is more to it, the code you provide can't possibly work. There is no `End Sub`, and the Sub and Function have the same name (that is the source of the immediate error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined Sub WOS and function. Leave only one of them. Try  to rove first row Sub WOS()

Comment: I left the Function portion of the code and now the Macro doesn't show anymore.  How would I need to change the code so I can use the formula =WOS(CellB1, RangeB2:B14)?

Comment: Csn u debug it? Do you call your function?

Comment: I debugged it and got the call to work. Thanks! Now I need to figure out why my logic isn't working properly.